# Не отображается Snackbar

Tags: android, kotlin

Пишу приложение в котором при определенных условиях срабатывает Snackbar его код:

```
 Snackbar.make(enterOrRegistration, "Вход выполнен", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
```

до строки действия доходят,но почему то не выводится сообщение.

Comment: Нужно больше информации. Приложите код активити и XML

Comment: судя по коду должен срабатывать, проверяйте еще раз

Comment: поставьте внутри обработчика брейкпоинт и попробуйте на него попасть. Может обработчик вызывается, но не делает того что вы хотите. Еще уточните где именно вызывается setOnClickListener. Может он и не вызывается

Comment: Ещё android:clickable="true" явно лишнее. Попробуйте убрать. И покажите как и где вы вашу кнопку в коде инициализируете

Comment: Проверил с помощь поинтов,оказалось что обработчик срабатывает но не срабатывает эта строчка; Snackbar.make(enterOrRegistration, "Введите ваш e-mail", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)

Comment: Точнее не отображается сообщение

Comment: Вы создали сообщение, но не вызвали показ: `show()`. `Snackbar.make(enterOrRegistration, "Вход выполнен", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы создали сообщение, но не вызвали показ методом `show()`.

```
Snackbar.make(enterOrRegistration, "Вход выполнен", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```